# How to merge a successful build of a pull request using a Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

TL;DR: Given the following declarative Jenkinsfile, how can I merge the pull request following a successful build? http://pastebin.com/uivA0MqF

In the (Multibranch) Job configuration, under Branch Source > Advanced I have the following setup:

[image]

And in GitHub I have a web hook that listens to `pull request` and `push` events.

**Edit:** I have attempted the following, but it currently fails with a syntax error:

```
def gitPullRequestNumber = null
...
...
stage ("Merge pull request") {
     steps {
        gitPullRequestNumber = sh "git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head:develop'"
        sh "curl -X PUT -d '{\'commit_title\': \'Merge pull request\'}'  <<GIT REPO URL>>/pulls/${gitPullRequestNumber}/merge?access_token=<<ACCESS-TOKEN"
     }
}
```

The error:

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:

```
WorkflowScript: 58: Expected a step @ line 58, column 13.
               gitPullRequestNumber = sh "git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head:develop'"
               ^

1 error
```

---

Background:

We have a `master` branch and a `develop` branch. Developers will be doing their pull requests against the `develop` branch where tests will be run. If the tests pass, the pull request should be merged into the branch. Review of the code is done before a pull request is opened. When decided, the `develop` branch is merged to the `master` branch. In the future there may even be only a single branch.

I understand that some may say that it is a good thing this doesn't happen but this is what we are currently trying to achieve.

As mentioned, this all works fine and the job starts and uses the Jenkinsfile for checking out the repo based on direct pushes and/or pull requests, the build starts, the tests run and so on... however the missing piece is merging the pull requests back.

Comment: Perhaps Jon S or @Christopher Orr could provide some info?

Comment: You can't assign variables in Declarative Pipeline, except for within `script` blocks.

Comment: As usual, your experience lights the way, Christopher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After also checking the checkbox for **Build origin PRs (merged with base branch)** this enabled a Jenkins-provided environment variable, `$CHANGE_ID` that in the case of a pull request, is the pull request number. This could then be used in the stage:

```
stage ("Merge pull request") {
    steps { 
        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'credential-value', usernameVariable: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'ACCESS_TOKEN_PASSWORD',)]) {
            sh "curl -X PUT -d '{\"commit_title\": \"Merge pull request\"}'  https://github.ibm.com/api/v3/repos/org-name/repo-name/pulls/$CHANGE_ID/merge?access_token=$ACCESS_TOKEN_PASSWORD"
        }
    }
}
```

Update: to verify the merge was actually successful:

```
script {
    sh "curl -o - -s -w \"\n%{http_code}\n\" -X PUT -d '{\"commit_title\": \"Merge pull request\"}'  https://github.ibm.com/api/v3/repos/****/****/pulls/$CHANGE_ID/merge?access_token=$JENKINSBOT_PSW | tail -1 > mergeResult.txt"

    def mergeResult = readFile('mergeResult.txt').trim()
    if (mergeResult != "200") {
        error "Unable to merge!"
    } else {
        // Send a Slack message, etc
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use git commands to merge as written

```
#Checkout main branch
git checkout master 

#Merge it with pull request (insert your pull id)
git merge --no-ff pull/ID/head:develop

#TEST Local Merge Branch Compilation If Desired
#msbuild ...

#Push merged information back to git
git push origin master
```

Comment: Finding out the pull request number as part of theJenkinsfile is exactly what am I asking for.

Comment: Try `git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head:develop'` as per [how to list all pull request with count of files changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182366/how-to-list-all-pull-request-with-count-of-files-changed). Or consider using ruby gem [git-pulls](https://github.com/schacon/git-pulls)

Comment: Sorry for being dense, but does `git ls-remote origin 'pull/*/head:develop'` provide the number of the current pull request that is being tested?

Comment: I've tried, but this currently fails. See my edited question.

Comment: FWIW, `git merge @{-1}` will merge from the previous branch you were on (though this might not work with the Git plugin, as it checks out commits, rather than branches). https://stackoverflow.com/a/17819027/234938 seems to have an answer.