# can variables stored in git repo file be used in jenkins build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-build-flow

I am creating a Jenkins Freestyle build and I'm pulling a git repo in the SCM. One of the files in the repo contains content related to the build. How can I pass them as variables and use them during the build. Are there any plugins which can be leveraged?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [declarative pipelien](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) (you can easily [convert your freestyle job into such a pipeline](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/admin-resources/latest/pipelines/declarative-pipeline-migration-assistant)), you can read the file, and trigger another job with, as parameters, content from that file.

You can see a (close-ish) example in "[Reading file from Workspace in Jenkins with Groovy script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59171992/6309)"

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Hello') {
         steps {
            script{
               git branch: 'Your Branch name', credentialsId: 'Your crendiatails', url: ' Your BitBucket Repo URL '
          
               def filePath = readFile "${WORKSPACE}/ Your File Location"                   
               def lines = filePath.readLines() 
               for (line in lines) {                                            
                  build(job: "anotherjob",
                        parameters:[$line]
               } // for
            } // script
         }// steps
      } // stage
   } // stages
} // pipeline
```

Comment: i have created 4 jobs using jenkins job builder , All the 4 jobs use different repo. In each repo there is file with corresponding mail list which needs to be read and updated in the post build step. I was looking for an option to read the contents of file as variable from a file in workspace and update it in postbuild

Comment: @Thani Exactly: what my answer illustrates is how to read that file. You can then assign it to an environment variable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525173/6309